# Changing \smalltableaux box size

Tags: packages, ytableau

I am using the ytableau package and would like to have something like \smalltableaux where the entries have a smaller font but with a slightly bigger box because, as it stands, I can't see the difference between the filling 1 and \overline{1}.[image]

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. This makes our lives easier and increases the chance of people helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You show no code for the bad example where the overline clashes.

Anyway, you can define an environment that uses small size for the cells contents. One needs to revert `smalltableaux` to `nosmalltableaux` because `\ytableausetup` does global settings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ytableau}

\makeatletter
%%% boxsize also does nosmalltableaux (why?)
%%% so we define a new key that doesn't
\pgfkeys{/ytableau/options,
 onlyboxsize/.value required,
 onlyboxsize/.code = {%
  \compare@YT{#1}{normal}%
  \ifeq@YT
   \xdef\macro@boxdim@YT{\expandonce@YT\boxdim@normal@YT}%
  \else
   \xdef\macro@boxdim@YT{#1}%
  \fi
 }
}
\makeatletter

\newenvironment{smallytableau}{%
  \ytableausetup{smalltableaux,onlyboxsize=1.2em}%
  \begin{ytableau}%
}{%
  \end{ytableau}%
  \ytableausetup{nosmalltableaux,boxsize=normal}%
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{ytableau}
1 & \bar{1} \\
\end{ytableau}
    
\begin{smallytableau}
1 & \bar{1} \\
\end{smallytableau}
    
\begin{ytableau}
1 & 2 \\
\end{ytableau}
    
\end{document}
```

I suggest `\bar` instead of `\overline`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, sorry for not adding the code, I am new here.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[boxsize=2em]{ytableau}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{ytableau}
        1& \overline{1} \\
    \end{ytableau}\\
     or \\
     
     \begin{ytableau}
        1& \none&\overline{1}
     \end{ytableau}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know you can change the size with boxsize, the problem was how to do so preserving the small font from \smalltableaux :)

Comment: @Babymonster After \begin{document} add the line

\tiny or the size you want

Comment: That doesn't work either, I have tried.

Comment: @Babymonster For me it worked very well.